# Proper way to use 'class_weight' for Multiclass Classification in XGBoostClassifier( ) in a Pipeline

Tags: python, machine-learning, scikit-learn, xgboost, xgbclassifier

I am working on a heavily imbalanced Multi-Class data for classification. I want to use the `class_weight` as given in many `scikit-learn` models. What is the best and proper way to do that **inside a pipeline**.

As I have seen in Documentation, `scale_pos_weight` is for binary classification only.
[This answer here with 15 upvotes by "Firas Omrane"](https://datascience.stackexchange.com/questions/16342/unbalanced-multiclass-data-with-xgboost/18823#18823) gives some idea  so I used

```
classes_weights = list(class_weight.compute_class_weight('balanced',
                                             classes = np.unique(y_train),
                                             y = y_train))

weights = np.ones(y_train.shape[0], dtype = 'float')
for i, val in enumerate(y_train):
    weights[i] = classes_weights[val-1]


XGBClassifier().fit(x_train, y_train, sample_weight=weights)
```

It works fine with `fit` but with the pipeline when used as:

```
('clf',XGBClassifier(class_weight = 'balanced', n_jobs = -1,objective = 'multi:softprob', sample_weight = classes_weights, )) # last step of the pipeline
```

it gives error as:

```
('clf',XGBClassifier(class_weight = 'balanced', n_jobs = -1,objective = 'multi:softprob', sample_weight = classes_weights, )) # last step of Pipeline

WARNING: /tmp/build/80754af9/xgboost-split_1619724447847/work/src/learner.cc:541: 
Parameters: { class_weight, sample_weight } might not be used.

  This may not be accurate due to some parameters are only used in language bindings but
  passed down to XGBoost core.  Or some parameters are not used but slip through this
  verification. Please open an issue if you find above cases.
```

Comment: That's not an error, it's a warning. What error are you getting?

Comment: Yeah! so it means it won't be used. How can I make it work then? Inside a pipeline?